# how to stop ssh command in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssh

i am connected to an ssh sever using a c# program.
the problem is when i send an ssh command to the server and their is no result the program hang and stop working.
how can i stop or cancel the ssh command after 3 second if the server is not responding ?

```
using (SshClient client = new SshClient("host", port, "user","pass"))
client.Connect();
                                    if (client.IsConnected)
                                    {
                                        var comcom = client.RunCommand("cat /etc/xxx/xxx.conf");
                                        string  resultt = comcom.Result.ToString();

                                        client.Disconnect();
}
```

any help please

Comment: Would `client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);` before `client.Connect();` work? I'm not sure whether that timeout is only for the first connection or every command.

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay
but it's not working
thanks again